# How to apply a function which gets the dataframe sliced with sliding window as a parameter in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, sliding-window

I've a time series data stored in pandas dataframe, which looks like this:

```
    Date         Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
0   2016-01-19   22.86   22.92   22.36   22.60   838024
1   2016-01-20   22.19   22.98   21.87   22.77   796745
2   2016-01-21   22.75   23.10   22.62   22.76   573068
3   2016-01-22   23.13   23.35   22.96   23.33   586967
4   2016-01-25   23.22   23.42   23.01   23.26   645551
5   2016-01-26   23.28   23.85   23.22   23.74   592658
6   2016-01-27   23.68   23.78   18.76   20.09   5351850
7   2016-01-28   20.05   20.69   19.11   19.37   2255635
8   2016-01-29   19.51   20.02   19.40   19.90   1203969
9   2016-02-01   19.77   19.80   19.13   19.14   1203375
```

I want to create an applicable function, which gets a slice of the original dataset what it can aggregate by any custom defined aggregation operator.

Lets say, the function is applied like this:

```
aggregated_df = data.apply(calculateMySpecificAggregation, axis=1)
```

where the **calculateMySpecificAggregation** gets a 3-sized slice of the original dataframe for each row of the original dataframe. 
For each row the parameter dataframe of function contains the previous and the next rows of the original dataframe.

```
#pseudocode example
def calculateMySpecificAggregation(df_slice):

    # I want to know which row was this function applied on (an index I would like to have here)
    ri= ???   # index of the row where was this function applied

    # where df_slice contains 3 rows and all columns
    return float(df_slice["Close"][ri-1] + \
               ((df_slice["High"][ri] + df_slice["Low"][ri]) / 2) + \ 
                 df_slice["Open"][ri+1])
    # this line will fail on the borders, but don't worry, I will handle it later...
```

I want to have the sliding window size parametrized, access to other columns of the row and know the row index of the original line where the function was applied on.

That means, in case of slidingWindow = 3, I want to have parameter dataframes:

```
#parameter dataframe when the function is applied on row[0]:
    Date         Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
0   2016-01-19   22.86   22.92   22.36   22.60   838024
1   2016-01-20   22.19   22.98   21.87   22.77   796745

#parameter dataframe when the function is applied on row[1]:
    Date         Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
0   2016-01-19   22.86   22.92   22.36   22.60   838024
1   2016-01-20   22.19   22.98   21.87   22.77   796745
2   2016-01-21   22.75   23.10   22.62   22.76   573068

#parameter dataframe when the function is applied on row[2]:
    Date         Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
1   2016-01-20   22.19   22.98   21.87   22.77   796745
2   2016-01-21   22.75   23.10   22.62   22.76   573068
3   2016-01-22   23.13   23.35   22.96   23.33   586967

#parameter dataframe when the function is applied on row[3]:
    Date         Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
2   2016-01-21   22.75   23.10   22.62   22.76   573068
3   2016-01-22   23.13   23.35   22.96   23.33   586967
4   2016-01-25   23.22   23.42   23.01   23.26   645551

...            

#parameter dataframe when the function is applied on row[7]:
    Date         Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
6   2016-01-27   23.68   23.78   18.76   20.09   5351850
7   2016-01-28   20.05   20.69   19.11   19.37   2255635
8   2016-01-29   19.51   20.02   19.40   19.90   1203969

#parameter dataframe when the function is applied on row[8]:
    Date         Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
7   2016-01-28   20.05   20.69   19.11   19.37   2255635
8   2016-01-29   19.51   20.02   19.40   19.90   1203969
9   2016-02-01   19.77   19.80   19.13   19.14   120375

#parameter dataframe when the function is applied on row[9]:
    Date         Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
8   2016-01-29   19.51   20.02   19.40   19.90   1203969
9   2016-02-01   19.77   19.80   19.13   19.14   1203375
```

I don't want to use a cycle combined with `iloc` indexing if possible.

I've experimented with `pandas.DataFrame.rolling` and `pandas.rolling_apply` with no success.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a long suffering I've solved the problem.
I couldn't avoid `iloc` (which is not a big problem in this case), but at least cycle is not being used here.

```
contextSizeLeft = 2
contextSizeRight = 3

def aggregateWithContext(df, row, func, contextSizeLeft, contextSizeRight):

    leftBorder  = max(0,       row.name - contextSizeLeft)
    rightBorder = min(len(df), row.name + contextSizeRight) + 1

    '''
    print("pos: ", row.name, \
          "\t", (row.name-contextSizeLeft, row.name+contextSizeRight), \
          "\t", (leftBorder, rightBorder), \
          "\t", len(df.loc[:][leftBorder : rightBorder]))
    '''

    return func(df.iloc[:][leftBorder : rightBorder], row.name)

def aggregate(df, center):
    print()
    print("center", center)
    print(df["Date"])
    return len(df)


df.apply(lambda x: aggregateWithContext(df, x, aggregate, contextSizeLeft, contextSizeRight), axis=1)
```

and the same for dates if anyone would need it:

```
def aggregateWithContext(df, row, func, timedeltaLeft, timedeltaRight):

    dateInRecord = row["Date"]
    leftBorder  = pd.to_datetime(dateInRecord - timedeltaLeft)
    rightBorder = pd.to_datetime(dateInRecord + timedeltaRight)

    dfs = df[(df['Date'] >= leftBorder) & (df['Date'] <= rightBorder)]
    #print(dateInRecord, ":\t", leftBorder, "\t", rightBorder, "\t", len(dfs))

    return func(dfs, row.name)

def aggregate(df, center):
    #print()
    #print("center", center)
    #print(df["Date"])
    return len(df)


timedeltaLeft  = timedelta(days=2)
timedeltaRight = timedelta(days=2)
df.apply(lambda x: aggregateWithContext(df, x, aggregate, timedeltaLeft, timedeltaRight), axis=1)
```